# Logstash Google Pubsub Input Plugin fails to load file and pull messages

Tags: google-cloud-platform, logstash, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm getting this error when trying to run Logstash pipeline with a configuration that is using [google_pubsub](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-input-google_pubsub) on a docker container running in my production env:

```
2021-09-16 19:13:25 FATAL runner:135 - The given configuration is invalid. Reason: Unable to configure plugins: (PluginLoadingError) Couldn't find any input plugin named 'google_pubsub'. Are you sure this is correct? Trying to load the google_pubsub input plugin resulted in this error: Problems loading the requested plugin named google_pubsub of type input. Error: RuntimeError

    you might need to reinstall the gem which depends on the missing jar or in case there is Jars.lock then resolve the jars with `lock_jars` command

no such file to load -- com/google/cloud/google-cloud-pubsub/1.37.1/google-cloud-pubsub-1.37.1 (LoadError)
2021-09-16 19:13:25 ERROR Logstash:96 - java.lang.IllegalStateException: Logstash stopped processing because of an error: (SystemExit) exit
```

This seems to randomly happen when re-installing the plugin. I thought it's a proxy issue but I have the google domain enabled in the whitelist. Might be the wrong one / missing something. Still, doesn't explain the random failures.

Also, when I run the pipeline in my machine I get GCP events, but when I do it on a VM - no Pubsub messages are being pulled. Could it be a firewall rule blocking them?

Answer (score 0):

The error message suggests there is a problem in loading the ‘google_pubsub’ input plugin. This error generally occurs when the input Pub/Sub plugin is not installed properly. Kindly ensure that you are installing the [Logstash Plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/7.13/plugins-inputs-google_pubsub.html) for Pub/Sub correctly.

For example, installing Logstash Plugin for Pub/Sub in a VM :

```
sudo -u root sudo -u logstash bin/logstash-plugin install logstash-input-google_pubsub
```

For a detailed demo refer to [this](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/exporting-stackdriver-elasticcloud) community tutorial.

Comment: Thanks. I'm using offline plugin pack installation and sometimes it presents this error and after a few tries it's being installed successfully. still not sure why

Comment: This issue seems more on the Plugin side. I would recommend opening this issue on the Elastic Cloud community [forum](https://discuss.elastic.co/)